# QPageSetupDialog crashes when printer set to a plotter

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, c++14

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem or at least how to catch it?

I use Qt 5.10:

```
QPageSetupDialog setupDlg(m_printer, this);
setupDlg.exec();
```

So with usual printer it works fine. But if I select plotter, it crashes with this error:

> "read access violation"

Comment: If you are running on Linux/Unix, try running your program as super user and see if still crashes?

Comment: No, I run it on Windows. I didnt check, but i think that there is no such problem on Linux.

Comment: Can you open the page setup for the plotter in Word or any other tool?

Comment: Yes. In other programs it works fine